# Seed head Identification. July in Toronto, Ontario, Canada

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers, seeds

What flower has this type of seed head? (this was shot on July 17th, 2020)  [image]

This was in a residential garden in Toronto. Going from memory, i believe the size was approx. 2 1/2" to 3" in diamater.

Comment: Looks like an allium to me, but I doubt anyone is going to be able to identify it more specifically from only this part of the plant - there are hundreds of alliums, both cultivated and wild. Do you have other photos of the rest?

Comment: Thank-you Bryan, that's really helpful. This is the only photo i have.

Comment: Alright; I'll post it as an answer. Possibly someone else will be able to narrow it down a bit more for you.

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like an allium, but you'll find many of these look quite similar at this stage, I doubt you can get much further than that. See for example a Google image search for [allium+flower+seeds](https://www.google.com/search?q=allium+flower+seeds) (added 'seeds' to the search to get later stages like the one you've got).

[Alliums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allium) include onions and garlic (both cultivated versions you'd commonly find in a grocery store and wild varieties; for onions this includes green onions and scallions as well as bulb onions), numerous other plants grown primarily for decorative purposes commonly called "allium", and lots of other wild plants.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @BryanKrause that this is an Allium seed head. The seed pod and seed on the end give it away

For another partial match from a commonly cultivated plant in domestic gardens, *[Agapanthus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agapanthus)* seed heads look similar, though the seed pod and seeds are elongated and winged. When these dehisce at the end of seeding you can be left with a head that superficially looks like OP's photo, but without the small black seeds. *Agapanthus* tend to be much larger, up to about 6 inches (15 cm) across, though there are many cultivars, some of which have smaller inflorescences.

Head with seed pods (from [gardeningknowhow.com](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/bulbs/agapanthus/cutting-back-agapanthus.htm), photo by eldadcarin):

[image: With seed pods]

Without pods (from [seenobjects.org](https://www.seenobjects.org/2005-05-09-web-head), photo by Martin Kenny):

[image: without pods]